# alt text appears backwards

Tags: html, css, right-to-left, alt

I am using a right-to-left language with `dir='rtl'` on the body element.

So the whole page flows as it should from right to left.

For some reason alt text within images are displayed backwards.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bbzsZ/).

Any simple solution?

Comment: That's what adding `dir="rtl"` does...

Comment: @Ben please look at the fiddle and you'll see the problem

Comment: I have no idea what is causing this as I never read or wrote in this kind of language, but even without dir="rtl" it is written differently.

Comment: So what is the solution that you want?

Comment: @Ben, well the alt text should look just like the text in the div, as they are identical. Why is the alt text backwards?

Comment: Even if you remove the `dir` attribute, the text displays the same. Adding in English characters works fine... It must be a rendering issue.

Comment: hmm Ok I was using Chrome (where it was backwards) . Now I just tried it on Firefox and it looks normal. I suppose that what @Lordex meant when he said that it looks ok

Comment: Fixed in Chrome 33, released February 2014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in Chromium, reported in 2010 as [RTL: Hebrew alt text rendered left-to-right when images disabled](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47672), with apparently no progress.

By the specifications, text entirely in Hebrew letters is to be displayed right to left independently of `dir` attribute settings. In some browsers, `dir=rtl` helps, but not here. For some reason, `alt` text rendering in Chrome does not apply directionality information the same ways as normal text rendering does – after all, it probably uses separate routines internally. Using control characters for directionality inside the attribute value does not help.

Comment: +1 thanks, @Jukka , so you're basically saying that there's no easy fix for chrome as yet?

Comment: @Danield, I’m afraid so. (I don’t dare to even think of suggesting “Visual Hebrew”...) What really puzzles me is that Chrome gets Arabic text in `alt` attributes right; `alt="مدن"` causes the characters to be rendered right to left.

Comment: Fixed in Chrome 33, released Feb 2014

Answer (score 4):

Everything looks OK for me in Firefox and IE. The problem with the `alt` text seems to only exist in Google Chrome. I suspect it's some kind of bug in Chrome (or WebKit, as Safari also exhibits the problem).

You could try setting character encoding on the document, which should fix the problem, apparently:

> ### Correct page encoding
>
> **The Symptom:**
>
> Your page looks garbled in Google Chrome. Garbage
>   characters may be displayed, and RTL language pages (e.g. Hebrew or
>   Arabic) may appear with their letters reversed.
>
> **The problem:**
>
> If character encoding is not specified precisely,
>   different browsers can interpret the encoding in different ways or not
>   at all. The impact on users is dire since it prevents them from
>   viewing the site.
>
> **Recommendations:**
>
> Declare your page's content-type correctly, this can either be in an HTTP header or a  Meta tag specified in your HTML. The character set your page uses must be a legal value from the Official
>   IANA List, please only use the encodings that have the text (preferred
>   MIME name) listed next to them e.g. ISO-8859-1, Shift_JIS. If you
>   specify two different values for the character encoding in the HTTP
>   Header and the Meta tag, Google Chrome will use the value in the HTTP
>   Header. Conflicting declarations of character encoding in the HTTP
>   Header and Meta tag is asking for trouble. More information on this
>   subject can be found here. We recommend using UTF-8 for all Web
>   content. If you have to use legacy encoding for some reason, make sure
>   to identify the encoding correctly as outlined above. For legacy
>   situations involving Hebrew sites use Logical Hebrew encoding
>   (ISO-8859-8-I). We strongly discourage the use of Visual Hebrew
>   encoding (ISO-8859-8). It has no place on the Web anymore and is a
>   remnant of old systems lacking logic for rendering RTL text. It causes
>   many bugs and lots of confusion.

The above was taken from > http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromecompatfaq

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, what alphabet are the characters from?

Comment: hmm I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bbzsZ/1/ adding a meta tag with what is think is the correct content type utf-8 but it still doesn't get corrected in chrome.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe give this a read? http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/

Comment: The information given about encodings and directionality in the answer and comments is as such correct and useful, but it does not seem to relate to the problem at hand. It’s the people who programmed Chrome that should have read the directionality tutorial!